# Regular Pentagon sides in terms of interior pentagon and segments connecting vertices

Tags: geometry

Diagonals of a regular pentagon $P$ form smaller interior pentagon $Q$. Let $d$ be the distance from any vertex of $P$ to the nearest vertex of $Q$. $a$ is the length of a side of $P$ and $b$ is the length of a side of $Q$. Prove that
$$d=(ab)^{1/2} = \sqrt{ab}$$
For some reason, my brain is glitching on this seemingly easy geometry problem. I know that by the property of similar triangles,
$$\frac{d}{b}=\frac{2d+b}{a}$$
Additionally, the interior angles are $108^\circ$, which when trisected to create smaller right triangle will be $\dfrac{108}{3}^\circ$. This would help in finding $d$, $a$, and $b$ in terms of trigonometry. However, this problem seems like it can be solved with similar triangles OR Pythagoras Theorem. Thank you in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can pick out another pair of similar triangles which gives
$$
\frac{a}{d}=\frac{2d+b}{a}.
$$
Thus $$\frac{a}{d} = \frac{d}{b}.$$
The pair is:  triangle formed by two adjacent sides and a diagonal of the big pentagon; and triangle formed by two edges joining a vertex of the small pentagon and two nearest vertices of the big pentagon and one side of the big pentagon.

Comment: Thats it!!!!!! thank you fredgoodman , your not just a good man your a greatman :) I see the other similar triangle that will lead to the solution . might u upvote sucha neat question?

Answer (score 0):

[image: similar triangles of SUT and TSR complete the proof]

similar triangles SUT and TSR along with the relation I found off the bat give the desired relation