Side of the small pentagon formed by diagonals of a regular pentagon

The side of a regular pentagon is $a$ and its diagonal is $b$. What is
the side of the small pentagon formed by connecting the diagonals of
the original pentagon?
$1)\dfrac{a+b}2\qquad\qquad2)a-b\qquad\qquad3)\dfrac{2a+b}3\qquad\qquad4)2a-b\qquad\qquad5)\dfrac12a+b$

Here is what I have tried:
As depicted in the image, each diagonal can be expressed in term of $2m+x$ (it follows from $\triangle QDC\cong \triangle PDE\cong \triangle TAE\cong \triangle SAB\cong \triangle RBC$ and each of them has the angles $36^{\circ},36^{\circ},108^{\circ}$).
In $\triangle BDE$ we have: $$\dfrac xa=\dfrac mb\quad\Rightarrow\quad \dfrac xa=\dfrac{(b-x)/2}{b}$$
$$2bx=a(b-x)\quad\Rightarrow\quad (a+2b)x=ab$$
Hence I got $x=\dfrac{ab}{a+2b}$. But unfortunately, this answer is not among the options.


I think you can get the answer using the calculations at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2681955/regular-pentagon-sides-in-terms-of-interior-pentagon-and-segments-connecting-ver – also, using the information at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4393781/regular-pentagon-and-diagonals

@GerryMyerson Thanks for the links. The result from the second one leads to answer right away (following form that the $\triangle RDC$ and $\triangle BQC$ have $36^{\circ},72^{\circ},72^{\circ}$ angles).

I could continue my work to find the correct option, using the well-known $b/a=\phi=\dfrac{1+\sqrt5}2$.
I've equated my expression ($x=\dfrac{ab}{a+2b}$) with each option:

$1)\dfrac{a+b}2\qquad\qquad2)a-b\qquad\qquad3)\dfrac{2a+b}3\qquad\qquad4)2a-b\qquad\qquad5)\dfrac12a+b$

First option:
$$\dfrac{ab}{a+2b}=\dfrac{a+b}{2}\quad\Rightarrow\quad a^2+ab+2b^2=0 \quad\Rightarrow\quad1+\phi+2\phi^2=0$$
which is wrong.
Second option:
$$\dfrac{ab}{a+2b}=a-b\quad\Rightarrow\quad a^2+ab-2b^2=ab \quad\Rightarrow\quad 1-2\phi^2=0$$
is wrong.
Third option:
$$\dfrac{ab}{a+2b}=\dfrac{2a+b}{3}\quad\Rightarrow\quad 2a^2+5ab+2b^2=3ab$$
$$a^2+ab+b^2=0\quad\Rightarrow\quad 1+\phi+\phi^2=0$$
is wrong
Fourth option:
$$\dfrac{ab}{a+2b}=2a-b\quad\Rightarrow\quad 2a^2+3ab-2b^2=ab$$
$$a^2+ab-b^2=0\quad\Rightarrow\quad 1+\phi-\phi^2=0$$
This is the correct answer!

Here is a geometric argument. Draw the pentagon $ABCDE$, its circumcircle, and the "small pentagon" $PQRST$ with vertices in the intersection of the diagonals of the initial pentagon. (My notation slightly differ.)

Using for instance the circumcircle, we see that the angles in $\Delta DTC$ are $36^\circ,72^\circ,72^\circ$, so it is isosceles, $CD=TD=a$. With the same argument $BP=BC=a$. So $b=BD=BP+TD-PT=2a-x$.

This is the same as in the comments of the question, here shown explicitly.
